# Retrieve network password (network share) from keychain in terminal

Tags: macos, keychain, smb, afp

How can I retrieve my NAS password from Keychain using the terminal? Using `security` I can retrieve both application and internet passwords, but I've been unsuccessful for those where kind is set to `network password`.

Using the `-D` flag of `find-generic-password` doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

After searching, it seems the case is important for the *kind*. The following worked for me with the following keychain config:

```
security find-internet-password -D "Network Password" -l "the_share" -w
```

[image]

Of course you can filter a bit more by indicating more element to your research

```
security find-internet-password -h
Usage: find-internet-password [-a account] [-s server] [options...] [-g] [keychain...]
    -a  Match "account" string
    -c  Match "creator" (four-character code)
    -C  Match "type" (four-character code)
    -d  Match "securityDomain" string
    -D  Match "kind" string
    -j  Match "comment" string
    -l  Match "label" string
    -p  Match "path" string
    -P  Match port number
    -r  Match "protocol" (four-character code)
    -s  Match "server" string
    -t  Match "authenticationType" (four-character code)
    -g  Display the password for the item found
    -w  Display only the password on stdout
If no keychains are specified to search, the default search list is used.
        Find an internet password item.
```

With the above results here's what are the fields (replace `-w` by `-g`)

```
security find-internet-password -D "Network Password" -l "the_share" -g
keychain: "/Users/bric3/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
version: 512
class: "inet"
attributes:
    0x00000007 <blob>="the_share"
    0x00000008 <blob>=<NULL>
    "acct"<blob>="the_user"
    "atyp"<blob>=<NULL>
    "cdat"<timedate>=0x32303139313233303133323534345A00  "20191230132544Z\000"
    "crtr"<uint32>=<NULL>
    "cusi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "desc"<blob>="Network Password"
    "icmt"<blob>=<NULL>
    "invi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "mdat"<timedate>=0x32303139313233303133323534345A00  "20191230132544Z\000"
    "nega"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "path"<blob>=<NULL>
    "port"<uint32>=0x00000000
    "prot"<blob>=<NULL>
    "ptcl"<uint32>="afp "
    "scrp"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "sdmn"<blob>=<NULL>
    "srvr"<blob>="the_share._afpovertcp._tcp.local"
    "type"<uint32>=<NULL>
password: "the password"
```

E.g. specifying the protocol using `-r "smb "` will not result in any result for me as it is an afp share, but using `-r "afp "` will, for this particular (Note that the extra space is mandatory for this particular criteria to work). But it's also possible to search for the account using `-a the_user`. But for this password specifying other fields (as they are `NULL`) will not return anything.

macOs 10.15.2